# Как скачивать изображения с помощью библиотеки requests в Python?

Tags: python, requests

Я установил библиотеку requests в Python 3.6. Необходимо скачать изображения по предоставленной ссылке на файл. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать? 
Доступ к изображению я получаю следующим образом:
img = r.get('URL here')

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [How to download image using requests](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13137817/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В респонсе будет атрибут content в котором содержится изображение в двоичном виде. Таким образом после получения ответа необходимо будет сохранить в его файл.

```py
 img = r.get("img_url")
 img_file = file('path_to_image', 'w')
 img_file.write(img.content)
 img_file.close()
```

Comment: во второй строчке нужно исправить по моему
`img_file = open('path_to_image', 'wb')`